# Trying to write to an output file using FileWriter

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm currently trying to save the output of my code into a text file, when I run it on a different project it generates the output file and stores the output respectively, however when I run the same code in a different project it gives me blank output file and I do not really know what's the matter. I'm confused as to where to put the .close() function and the flush function as well. Thank you in advance!

```
    FileWriter output = new FileWriter("set.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
    InputStream fis_n = new     FileInputStream("/Users/User/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test/sample.txt");
    InputStreamReader isr_n = new InputStreamReader(fis_n, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader br_n = new BufferedReader(isr_n);

 while ((input = br_n.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] s = input.split(":");
        if (s[1].equals(text)) {
            writer.write(s[0] + "'s result is " + sample_text);
            writer.newLine();
            break;
        }
 }
  writer.close();
  output.close();
```

This is what the edited code looks like, yet still the output file "set.txt" is empty upon running the program.

```
    FileWriter output = new FileWriter("set.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
    InputStream fis_n = new     FileInputStream("/Users/User/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test/sample.txt");
    InputStreamReader isr_n = new InputStreamReader(fis_n, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader br_n = new BufferedReader(isr_n);

  try {
        while ((input = br_n.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] s = input.split(":");
        if (s[1].equals(text)) {
            writer.write(s[0] + "'s result is " + sample_text);
            writer.newLine();
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
            fis_n.close();
            isr_n.close();
            br_n.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // fis_n.close();
    //isr_n.close();
    //br_n.close();
}
```

This is what the final code looks like:

```
     public static void dictionary(String sample_text, String text) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

 try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new      FileInputStream("/Users/User/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test/sample.txt"),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")
        ));
             try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("/Users/User/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test/set.txt"),
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")
            ));
            try {
                String input;
                while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] s = input.split(":");
                    if (s[1].equals(text)) {
                        writer.write(s[0] + "'s result is " + sample_text);
                        writer.newLine();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error handling
    }
  }
```

This is the main method where the dictionary method is being called.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

 case 2: {
                BufferedReader d_br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("/Users/User/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test/input_file.txt"),
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8")
                ));

                try {

                    String d_line;
                    while ((d_line = d_br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String h_input = test(d_line);
                    dictionary(d_line, h_input);

                    }
                } catch(IOException e){

                }finally {
                    d_br.close();
                }
                break;
            }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's writing to the location you are expecting? `"set.txt"` is a relative path. It is relative to the _working directory_ of your program. Maybe the blank `set.txt` that you are seeing is _not_ one created by the program _as it is currently being invoked_. One easy way to sanity-check this is: delete the empty `set.txt`, and run your program again. Does your program generate another empty `set.txt` to replace it?

Comment: @Birchlabs Yes it does, whenever I run the program again, a new "set.txt" file is created.

Answer (score 3):

You should put `writer.close()` after the `while` loop, and preferable, into the `finally` section.

If there is no requirement to store partially-processed files (as in most cases), you may remove `flush` at all. In the other case, it is better to leave it where it is.

The generic case of resource usage on Java 7+ looks like follows (this syntax is called [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (
    Resource resource1 = // Resource 1 initialization
    Resource resource2 = // Resource 2 initialization
    ...
) {
    // Resource utilization
} catch (XXXException e) {
    // Something went wrong
}
```

Resource are freed (closed) automatically by try-with-resources.

If you need to use Java 6 or earlier, the above code could be roughly translated to the following (actually there are some subtle differences, that is not important at this level of details).

```
try {
    Resource1 resource1 = // Resource initialization
    try {
        Resource2 resource2 = // Resource initialization
        try {
            // Resource utilization
        } finally {
            // Free resource2
            resource2.close();
        }
    } finally {
        // Free resource1
        resource1.close();
    }
} catch (XXXException e) {
    // Something went wrong
}
```

Notice, how nested `try-finally` blocks used for resource management.

In your particular case we need to manage two resources: `Reader` and `Writer`, so the code will look as follows:

```
try (
        // Notice, we build BufferedReader for the file in a single expression
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("sample.txt"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8 // Better replacement for Charset.forName("UTF-8")
        ));
        // Alternative way to do the same
        // BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sample.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // Output charset for writer provided explicitly
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("set.txt"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        ))
        // Alternative way to do the same
        // BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("set.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
) {
    String input;
    while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] s = input.split(":");
        if (s[1].equals(text)) {
            writer.write(s[0] + "'s result is " + text);
            writer.newLine();
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error handling
}
```

Or, using pre-Java7 syntax:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("sample.txt"),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")
    ));
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("set.txt"),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")
        ));
        try {
            String input;
            while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] s = input.split(":");
                if (s[1].equals(text)) {
                    writer.write(s[0] + "'s result is " + text);
                    writer.newLine();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error handling
}
```

Comment: this still causes the output file to contain nothing.

Comment: Try to add debug output to the nested `if`. It will allow to check whether something is really written to the file.

Comment: adding the following shows that nothing is written to the file as well ...   if (DEBUG) {
                    writer.write("debug testing");
                }

Comment: This still gives a blank output file though

Comment: Print debug output to the console, so you can see if you really output anything to the file (probably not).

Comment: I've just figured out the reason for the empty txt file. Reflected in the question, I'm running a while loop in the main method

Comment: @kgeorgiy Just a remark about your code for Java prior to version 6. When you call `close`, you can get a `NullPointerException`, if you do not check for `null`.

Comment: @thatguy No, that cannot happen. We initialize resource before corresponding `try-finally` block. If resource is initialized successfully, it is not `null`. If initialization thrown an exception, the whole `try-finally` block will be skipped, so `close` will not be called.

Comment: @Scarl Probably you should refactor resource management in the `main` method, in the same way as in `dictionary` method.

Comment: That's what I did as well, but it still generates the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you call the `flush` method of a writer, whenever you want the current buffer to be written immediately. If you just write a file completely without any intermediate operation on your output, you do not need to call it explicitly, since the `close` call will do that for you.

Secondly, you only call the `close` method of the *top-level* reader or writer, in your case `BufferedWriter`. The `close` call is forwarded to the other assigned readers or writers. Multiple consecutive `close` calls do not have any effect on a previously closed instance, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()).

As a general note to using readers and writers, consider this pattern:

```
// This writer must be declared before 'try' to
// be visible in the finally block
AnyWriter writer = null;

try {

    // Instantiate writer here, because it can already
    // throw an IOException
    writer = new AnyWriter();

    // The the writing in a loop or as you wish
    // If you need to write out the buffer in 
    // between, call flush

} catch (IOException e) {

    // Something went wrong while writing

} finally {

    try {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Exception while trying to close
    }

}
```

The `finally` block is ALWAYS executed. If you need a more compact syntax and you use at least Java 7, you can have a look at the `try-with` notation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect the br_n and other missing variables. And the output file is still empty :o

Comment: @Scarl The variables `input` and `sample_text` are still missingand your corrected code also misses a bracket. Nevertheless, I tested it and it works. Try to test it with **bold**absolute paths**bold** for both files, like `c:/test/sample.txt` and `c:/test/set.txt`. I assume, that there is a problem with reading the input file, since you have stated that the output file is created and thee are no other dependencies.

Comment: Generic scheme, explained in my answer is both easier and contains less boilerplate (two-resource example contains the same number of statements as single-resource example provided here).

Comment: @kgeorgiy So? That is what i refered to in the last sentence, which is only applicable for at least Java 7, so I focused on the general case.

Comment: The problem turned out to be in the main method where I call the dictionary method. Everytime the method exits, the output file is closed once a match is found it creates a newer filer everytime. I've fixed the resources well with the try blocks however, upon exit, the file is still empty :o